# Kivy app takes 30 seconds to open in android device

Tags: python, android, kivy

After my kivy app is pushed to my android device through buildozer,
First I can see Kivy loading symbol,then screen is blank for 30 seconds. after that my app is getting opened.
And this is happening on first run as well as subsequent runs.

I have read some answers and got to know that "we can avoid this problem by starting with minimal GUI
and loading the rest more lazily".

Could any one please let me know,how we can load like this when the app opens?

Answer (score 0):

For an example, if you used on_pre_enter function and if you give this function to do many things, its normal you to wait much a time. But there is a no any code so i can't analyze your code and give any tip.Your computer's and android's processing time depends on background applications, hardware and many things does that. So try to share your minimal code just like your starting functions or you can create minimal application which has these functions so you can test your codes partly.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. But i tried splitting kv file and added lru_cache function where required. Both reduced some execution time.